# Placing the name of MOSFET

Tags: circuitikz, text, naming

How can I set the text to be on the right side of the MOSFET?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[circuit ee IEC]
\draw (3.5,14.5)  to [Tnigfete=T]  (3.5,16);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The default label location in this case is centered at the component origin.  You will need a separate node instead.

Answer (score 2):

Currently defined as nodes, the old definition is used when you do not want to name each pin. Normally label position is defined by `l_=` or `l^=` but for that component it does not work, the definition as a node allows scaling the component. Check page 45 circuiTikZ manual version 0.8.3 .

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% New version uses a node component definition.:
\draw(0,-0.5) node[nigfete,scale=2] (T1) {}
(T1.bulk) node[anchor=west] {T1}
(T1.G) node[anchor=east] {G}
(T1.D) node[anchor=west] {D}
(T1.S) node[anchor=north] {S};

% You can conect using the node pins labels.
\draw(0,3.5) to [R,l_=R] (T1.D);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```